# Electronically verify whether a cable is connected to an RJ45 connector

Tags: connector, rs485, detection, test

#### Background:

I have a device that interfaces with a motor controller over RS-485 via an RJ45 socket. Currently, the port is a standard 4x2 RJ45 connector with the RS-485 using pins 2 and 7.

[image: Eagle Circut]

Currently my startup procedure tries to connect to the controller 3 times before notifying the user `Device Cannot be found. Check cable`.

#### Problem:

I would like a way to electronically check if the cable is plugged in. By any chance, do 10-pin RJ45 sockets exist where two pins short if a cable is plugged in? If so, what is this feature called? If not, what is a solution used to detect if a cable is present in the system?

Comment: You could short one of the pairs at the motor controller, and then check to see at the other end if there is a short circuit

Comment: Yes, assuming no other solutions, that's the way I plan to go. Only issue is the controller is not easy to modify, so I would need to add a small PCB and use two Ethernet cables.

Comment: are both ends of the cable pluggable? ,... if not, then you only need to short two wires in the cable

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the transceivers you have you might be able to go with something like these:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt257/slyt257.pdf

https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/www/doc/application-note/an1593.pdf

It seems you don't, but if you had full access to modify both sides you could also try something even easier:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232237/is-it-possible-to-know-the-connection-status-of-a-rs232-port